# How to connect a discord bot to a website

Tags: html, css, web, discord.js, bots

How can I connect my Discord bot to my HTML website?

I don't need a dashboard. I just need to show how many servers my bot is in. On my website, how can I do this and which backend language should I use?

Which is the best backend language for web development?

My HTML content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <div class="topnav">
         <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
         <a href="#news">News</a>
         <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
         <a href="#about">About</a>
       </div>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <title>Beast Bot</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="title">
           <P>Beast Bot :)</P>

              <img class="img" src="images/kisspng-portable-network-graphics-computer-icons-transpare-braingoodgames-5c9d9c5093e378.8617067815538330406058.png">

        </div>

    </div>
      </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. What have you tried so far? If your bot is using discord.js, which is already using the node.js backend language, just use node.js. In fact, you can run both the discord bot and the webserver for your website on the same node.js environment, allowing you to easily share information between your webserver and discord bot.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `client.guilds.size` to get the amount of servers it's in. Assuming the web server and the bot are on the same server then, I would write the raw count of the amount of servers it's in to a file that the public can access from a browser.

Using jQuery (by adding `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>` to your head) you can do a GET request to the publicly accessible URL that has that number, like this:

```js
$.get("/path/to/data", data => {
  // Your code here to display it. The data variable will have the page's content
})
```

Comment: ok i got it but how i can get the url which has the number

Comment: Where ever your site's directory is, is where you want to output the number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an API to fetch data from your bot's back end. Frameworks like [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/) are great for making a REST API from scratch.

Comment: Can you flesh this out with examples of how one could add this to a typical web site?

Comment: You could import the Express app component in a `<script>` tag, use `app.get()` to fetch from the API, then use '<el>.innerHtml = res;` to display the result.

Comment: Please [edit] to update instead of commenting.